# Regularly printing to Adobe PDF from Excel, script to force PDFs to be saved to correct path

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, printing

I am working on a series of XLS files in Excel. When I am done with them, I need to print them to PDF so that they can be transmitted to a party outside my firm.

I recorded a fairly basic macro to allow me to print these files with the same setting every time. Unfortunately, it is not doing everything I need it to do.

Basically, I want Adobe to ask me where the file should be saved when it's being printed. That is not taking place right now with my script. If I manually print and select the settings "Ask to replace existing PDF file" from the Printer Properties window in Excel, it always asks me where the file should be saved. My script is not catching this, however, and I'm not sure what I need to add.

I have a lot of files to go through (and this is a task that will recur) so the sooner I get this nailed down the better.

Is this something that I can address with my Excel macro, and if so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Sub PrintToAdobeRedactions()
'
' PrintToAdobeRedactions Macro
' Print redacted worksheets to Adobe with correct settings every time.
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e
'
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "[Tab]"
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = "Page [Page]"
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintSheetEnd
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlOverThenDown
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use Save As PDF?  Why print to PDF?

Comment: @Chrismas007 -1st line reads .xls files, does the OP have xl'07 or newer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To SaveAs a PDF:

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim SaveName as String
    SaveName = InputBox("Save As File Name?")
    ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & SaveName & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great - although I changed "ThisWorkbook" to "ActiveWorkbook" so that I could use the macro to print out workbooks in other files. Thanks!